# Show that the subspace F is a subspace of F + G

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I need to prove that if $F,G$ are subspaces of the vector space $E$, then $F$ is a subspace of $F + G$.

$F$ is closed under adition and multiplication, because it is a subpace of $E$, thus I'm left with proving that $0_{F+G} \in F$.

Lets say that $E = \mathbb{R}, F = \mathbb{R}^{+}_{0}, G = \mathbb{R}^{-}_{0} $. In this case, $0_{F+G} \in F$. I'm not sure if this is always the case, and I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: The zero vector for a given vector space is unique. So $\mathbf{0} \in V$ is the same for all it's subspaces $F$ and $F+G$.

Comment: Do you mean $E$ instead of $V$?

Answer (score 1):

You are already given that $F$ and $G$ are subspaces of $E$. Are you convinced that $F+G$ is a subspace of $E$? If so, then all that remains to show is that $F \subseteq F+G$ since it is given that $F$ is a vector space in its own right.